# Print Button function in Salesforce

Tags: apex, javascript

I have created a print button and passed following javascript method :-
[image]

When I am clicking on the button Print I am getting below error:-
[image]

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @vidya you can't use apex code on Custom button. This code only use on Visualforce pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you did everything correct except the code you added in the text area.

Visualforce code can't be executed here. Only javascript code will be  executed here

You just need `window.print();`

Just put this in text box and try

Answer (score 1):

You can't use apex tags in custom java script buttons.  Just use `window.print();` in your custom button it will automatically redirect you to print page.

[image]